# Thank you message not visible when submitting iframe form with long content, need to scroll up parent to see it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm placing a form (that I host) on [this demo page](https://smg-studios.com/iframe-test-parent.html) (cross-domain).
I can add code on both parent and child.

The iframe auto-resize works perfect (using [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)), but when submitting the form on mobile or desktop with narrow window (so longer scrollbar) the thank you message is not visible right away. You need to scroll the parent page up a bit to see it which may cause confusion to people.

The iframe is perfectly shrunken down to the right size, but somehow need to do a custom postMessage to tell the parent to scroll/jump their page up to the top of the embedded iframe.

Any thoughts on how to use the already existing iframe-resizer script or can i just do a postMessage without it, if yes how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`document.getElementById('thankyou').scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Hi Andrii, no, will try that. Problem is I don't know how to send custom postMessage to parent saying "form_submitted". I use the iframe-resizer script, but how can I just send a simple postmessage to the parent? I mean, the iframe-resize script already added the message listeners so I have to make a check inside the iFrameListener(event) function that if message is "form_submitted", the scrollIntoView is executed. 

I know where I have to do the postMessage, just don't know how to (easily) send it with just a simple message like "form_submitted".

Comment: I know the syntax is like "target.postMessage(message, targetOrigin)" but don't know how to correctly set target and targetOrigin. I don't know the parent domain (i do know in the demo of course, but it could be placed anywhere). Also, it has to work well with the iframe-resize script.

Comment: The postMessage will not work unless the parent has the code to receive the message.

Comment: You could just keep the height of the iframe constant. So after sumbmitting the form, the iframe does not have to be resized.

Comment: Hi Andrii, I think i found the answer in the [iframeResizer.contentWindow.js)](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.js) file.

Comment: @Ralph Keep in mind it requires iframeResizer.js on host page. As you mentioned it could be placed anywhere.